# laravel result of 2 objects in one array

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I have 2 objects, the first retrieves the comments of the object work and the second retrieves the comments of the object achievement. I want to display the results in a single table containing the list of comments.

```
$posts1 =\DB::table('posts')
->select('posts.*', 'profils.nom_profil', 'works.titre', 'profils.imagelogo', 'works.description', 'works.like', 'works.nlike')
->join('works', 'posts.work_id','=','works.id')
->join('profils', 'posts.profil_id','=','profils.id')
->where('works.profil_id',$id)
->orderBy('posts.id', 'desc')
->paginate(10);

$posts2 =\DB::table('posts')
->select('posts.*', 'profils.nom_profil', 'achievs.titre', 'profils.imagelogo', 'achievs.description', 'achievs.like', 'achievs.nlike')
->join('achievs', 'posts.achiev_id','=','achievs.id')
->join('profils', 'posts.profil_id','=','profils.id')
->where('achievs.profil_id',$id)
->orderBy('posts.id', 'desc')
->paginate(10);
```

in view :

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
.
.
.
@endforeach
```

Comment: you should add ->get() to both queries to make them collections first, then you can merge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using Laravel 5.3, using get will return arrays of results as mentioned by @iCode, then you can use the native array_merge.

```
$posts = array_merge($posts1->get(),$posts2->get());
```

or add the get() method to your queries and just do

```
$posts = array_merge($posts1,$posts2);
```

Answer (score 2):

There can be many sloution for this but easiest one is to [`merge`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-merge) the objects as:

```
$posts = $posts1->merge(posts2);
```

**Update**

Try the merge as:

```
$posts= $posts1->merge($posts2->all())
```

Comment: I have this error Trying to get property of non-object in view         @foreach($posts as $post)
 {{($post->visit == '0')}} :

Comment: you should add ->get() to both queries to make them collections first, then you can merge

Comment: I have this error Call to a member function merge() on a non-object. when I add ->get() for both!

Comment: Check the updated answer. If this doesn't work then please show the result of `dd($posts)` after doing merge.

Comment: It works, but how do I make the pagination? also I have this error Call to a member function merge() on a non-object when I add  ->get() for both!

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin The `paginate` method returns an instance of  `Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator` which can make dynamic calls to the collection function.

Comment: In Laravel 5.2  `get` method returns an array so `merge` will not work.  For pagination to work check out the [manually-creating-a-paginator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator) in docs.

Comment: Didn't get your question? It will be ideally if you ask another question related to pagination as it seems totally different what you have asked initially.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129110/discussion-between-nabil-and-icode).